# Graph DB Frequently Suspended or Inactive

Tags: graphdb

I am using Graph DB 8 free version for the project. Frequently the database becomes inactive. I don't know the exact reason. Kindly resolve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GraphDB Cloud you should know that non-paid databases are suspended hourly when inactive. This can be resolved by upgrading to a higher tier.

http://cloud-docs.ontotext.com/display/S4docs/FAQ#FAQ-Mydatabasegotsuspended.Why%3F